# Call a website's html be loaded from an html local file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I want to call facebook.com through a local html file with the use of jquery.load() and some php proxy.

is this possible?

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to proxy facebook requests to steal passwords?

Comment: @StefanKendall no.....i am making my diploma on making a script that will secure the communication between the facebook users.It will use pgp cryptography for all communication between the user and the encrypt and decrypt  functions will run on the user's browser;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Facebook JSONP API.

Comment: i dont want to use facebook api.this will require asking permission from facebook.

Comment: @vkefallinos: Wrong; you don't need special permissions.  Scraping the site without the API may be illegal and is likely to get your IP banned.